Avalonia data binding: Unable to resolve property or method of name 'ItemHeight' on type 'Avalonia.Controls.Window'
Im having a realy hard time with data binding in avalonia. The first textblock in the code binds the value ItemHeight properly but the one insde ItemsControl doesnt. I think its the way i use relative layout that causes the issuse.
<!-- This works -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemHeight}" Height="{Binding ItemHeight}"></TextBlock>
<ItemsControl x:Name="TimeSlotsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding TimeSlots}" Grid.Row="1"       Grid.Column="0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <!-- This doesnt works -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ItemHeight}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

I have tried a lot of varitaion but cant make it work.

I managed to solve it using ReflectionBinding instead of regular Binding.

You may also not use Compiled Bindings by default. At least, you would have to set the x:DataType attribute.
